# Coming back in Reunion (French but not Schengen) and Germany (Schengen)

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, france, australian-citizens, reunion-island

My daughter visited me from September 4, 2016 to January 24, 2017.  She is Australian, she didn't need a visa (Australians may stay 3 months without visa).

But she needed to stay a little bit more, because her baby was sick. The *préfecture* in Reunion gave her a one month stay permission.

Now she wants to come back to Reunion for some days (July 5th) and we want to fly together to France and then Germany (July 17th).

Is she allowed to come back to Reunion? Can she travel into the Schengen area on these dates? (Her baby is German, so for him is no problem.)

Answer (score 4):

[Réunion does **not** apply the 90 days in a 180-day rule that the Schengen Area does](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=AU&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=RE&selDest=Reunion&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL) (except for Colombians). Which means, she can enter Réunion.

As for the Schengen Area, her stay in Réunion has nothing to do with that, so it'll count as a new 180-period when she enters, during which she can stay for 90 days

As for her baby, as you probably know, only his passport or ID card is needed